# Import admin form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to retrieve the form django-admin uses to create a model.

Django allows [the creation of a form matching some model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/), however the admin is much more powerful with the use of a ModelAdmin.

For instance, this code lets me add multiple tags to an article :

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('author', 'type', 'date')
    inlines = [
        TagInline,
    ]
```

I believe Django offers some way to get the resulting HTML and logic, do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Inline Model Admin objects to create Inline tags

[Link Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

For ex:

```
class TagInline(admin.TabularInline):
     model = Tag
     extra = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use tabular Inline.....

```
class Name(admin.TabularInline):
     model = name
```

Comment: That's what I have told above. Don't just copy paste

Answer (score 0):

Create inline model for Class TagInline given below:

```
class TagInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Tag
```